# Reset-ComputerMachinePassword on a Remote Machine

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword` on my domain controller.  I need to do this because of a trust issue with the server and the computer.  And the local administrator is disabled.  Is there a way to run this command (or an equivalent command) remotely to get reset the trust relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting computer password on a DC is different from that of member server.[See this blog](http://strongline.blogspot.ca/2007/09/how-to-reset-secure-channel-for-dcs.html)